# how to have a code read a specific line of an array via a str input

Tags: python, text-files

for the code I'm doing I have to have the user input a 3-letter str input, the input should be the first item on one of the lines of a txt file. the code should search each line of the txt file for the user input and return the line of text with the user input as a string. unfortunately I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum that you should expect to write your code for you. Since you are a new user, you are probably not aware of this. In future, whenever asking any question, you need to show some effort of you actually solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a rough draft to help you get started:

```py
pattern = "abc"

for line in file.readlines():
  if line.startswith(pattern):
    print(line)
```

Goals:

- Ask for the pattern using `input` ([url](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_user_input.asp));
- Read about [files](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/);
- Get acquainted with [string methods](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string);

The last bullet point is something I really advise doing with all the built in types, for example, lists, tuples, dictionaries...

Comment: thanks mate, i think i have a rough idea of what to do now

Comment: Np! If my answer helped, please accept it :)